# Cannot use readMavenPom in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-2

I am working on a Jenkinsfile for use with Jenkins 2.0.  The `readMavenPom` method is not recognized.  Is there some configuration I am missing to make this available?

My Jenkinsfile:

```groovy
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  checkout scm
  env.PATH = "${tool 'maven-3'}/bin:${env.PATH}"
  stage 'Build'
  def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
  echo "${pom}"
  sh "mvn -DskipTests=true verify"
}
```

When run, I get the following error:

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'readMavenPom' found among
> [AWSEBDeployment, archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo,
> emailext, error, fileExists, git, input, isUnix, load, mail, node, parallel,
> properties, pwd, readFile, retry, sh, slackSend, sleep, stage, stash, step, svn,
> timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withCredentials, withEnv, wrap,
> writeFile, ws]
> ```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I needed to install the `pipeline-utility-steps` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use this step, note the below from writeMavenPom/readMavenPom documentation:

> Avoid using this step and readMavenPom. It is better to use the sh step to run mvn goals

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writemavenpom-write-a-maven-project-file

Comment: (I found) Maybe because of https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/pull/47/

Answer (score 0):

1. **Use below command to read whole pom.xml in declarative pipeline  :**

   ```
    sh  ‘mvn -f  ./path-to-my-service/pom.xml help:evaluate -Dexpression=project -q -DforceStdout’
   ```
2. **For specific property in a pom.xml use same command with tag hierarchy :**
   project.property.sub-property........and so on

   ```
      def pom_version = sh script: 'mvn -f ./path-to-my-service/pom.xml -DskipTests help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true;

      def pom_artifactId = sh script: 'mvn -f ./path-to-my-service/pom.xml -DskipTests help: evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true;

      def pom_groupId = sh script: 'mvn -f ./path-to-my-service/pom.xml -DskipTests help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout', returnStdout: true;
   ```